# How to correctly use the PHP function 'fgets'?

Tags: php, iis, fgets

I assume I'm using the `fgets()` wrong. I'm tring to open a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file and then try to match a line in that file with a variable I create. If the line does match then I want to write/insert PHP code to the file right below that line. Example:

```
function remove_admin(){
    $findThis = '<tbody id="users" class="list:user user-list">';
    $handle = @fopen("../../fns-control/users.php", "r"); // Open file form read.

    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
        {
            $buffer = fgets($handle, 479); // Read a line.
            if ($buffer == '<tbody id="users" class="list:user user-list">') // Check for string.
            {
```

Now I want to write PHP code to the file, starting on line 480. How can I do that?

Useful information may be: [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) 6 and PHP 5.2.

Comment: for a one of, maybe, but those seems like a really bad way to handle anything with php -- and especially if the function name is accurate.

Comment: I'd agree with Dagon, this seems like a bad idea, i've written some code for you to do it anyway, but I recommend you ask a new question about how you should be doing this function, or how your user access control works. It doesn't seem to be the safest.

Comment: ooohhhh.....i just grabbed this from one of the first tutorials i found. I have little idea of what the function is designed to do.

Comment: @user524007 could you link us to the "tutorial" ?

Comment: @mfonda I'm sure I'll get punished for this but I'm not sure why I said tutorial. I wish I could just go back and give the function name "get_lovable_puppies" and then all would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function remove_admin(){
     $path = "../../fns-control/users.php";
     $findThis = '<tbody id="users" class="list:user user-list">';
     $phpCode = '<?php echo \'hello world\'; ?>';

     #Import file to string
     $f = file_get_contents($path);

     #Add in the PHP code
     $newfile = str_replace($findThis, $findThis . $phpCode, $f);

     #Overwrite the existing file
     $x = fopen($path, 'w');
     fwrite($x, $newfile);
     fclose($x);
 }
```

Comment: ok looks great to me. I'll give a shot and let you know how it turns out.